# How to get data from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

I am using PHP.
I have following tables

```
1)Posts

||  post_id  |  post  |  date_posted  ||


2) Photo

||  photo_id  |  photo  |  date_posted||


3) Video

||  video_id  |  video  |  video_link  |  date_posted||
```

I want to retrieve all rows present in all tables and order  by date_posted.

I want to differentiate later after retrieving rows which one is video and which one is post

How can i do this?

Comment: You can use `UNION ALL` but what are the datatypes of columns post, photo and video?

Comment: so there is no relation between these tables at all, you just want to output them together?  can you show what SQL you might have tried so far?

Comment: no relation just output in order they have been posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT post_id as id, post as data, date_posted FROM Posts
UNION ALL
SELECT photo_id, photo, date_posted FROM Photo
UNION ALL
SELECT video_id, video, date_posted FROM Video
ORDER BY date_posted DESC
```

maybe?..

Comment: this is not how i wanted 
this query just populates under alias names from all the tables
how would i differentiate which one is video and which one is post

Comment: then you should use @Curt's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 (
   SELECT video_id   AS id,
          'Post'     AS content_type,
          post       AS content,
          date_posted
     FROM Posts

        UNION ALL

   SELECT photo_id   AS id,
          'Photo'    AS content_type,
          photo      AS content,
          date_posted
     FROM Photo

           UNION ALL

   SELECT video_id   AS id,
          'Video'    AS content_type,
          video      AS content,
          date_posted
     FROM Video
 )
 ORDER BY date_posted DESC
```